# How to remove system path variable in windows

Tags: windows

I want to remove some of the path variables. I tried to do this using user-interface but it is not visible there it is only visible in command line.

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>path
PATH=C:\ProgramData\Boxstarter;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin;C:\xampp\php;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin;C:\Program Files\nodejs\
```

> C:\xampp\php

here C:\xampp\php is only visible in cmd but not in user interface. Can anyone please tell me how to remove this.

Answer (score 1):

There are two Path variables, one is in User variables, the other is in System variables.
Did you check both?

It's in `Advanced System settings` -> `Advanced` -> `Environment Variables`
And there will be two separated panes, above for User variables, below for System variables.
Check the values in both, the output of `path` will be those two combined.

Comment: i did check in both of them but they are not there.

Comment: @adityakumar  Have you tried open another cmd window and check it again? It might be a left value. Old environment value won't change within the window until you close it.

Comment: yeah i did check that in other cmd window it is available everywhere in cmd but not in Environment Variables window.

Comment: @adityakumar  That's weird. Then I guess there's a process of xampp maintaining it. Try check taskmgr, see if you can find it.

Comment: If you don't see it in either the system or user `Path` value, try defining a new variable in the GUI editor. This will broadcast a `WM_SETTINGCHANGE` "Environment" message to top-level windows. Explorer should reload its environment in response to this message. Next, run cmd.exe from Explorer (e.g. via the Win+R run dialog) and check the value of `PATH`.